# React Native with redux: Can we have initial payload for actions

Tags: react-native, redux, action

By design, do we allowed to have default payload when defining the Actions?

```
export const fetchApi = (payload = { propA: 'asdf', propB: new Date() ... etc }) => {
   return {
     type: 'FETCH_DATA',
     payload: payload
   };
}
```

Note: Can it be used as a signature of this payload? I mean the payload which passing in must have these data.

Comment: "I mean the payload which passing in must have these data". I afraid it's hard. Maybe TypeScript can.

Comment: With TypeScript you definitely can, I use it all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a default payload in your reducer if you want. For example in your Action.js:

```
export const fetchApi = (payload) => {
   return {
     type: 'FETCH_DATA',
     payload: payload
   };
}
```

And in your Reducer.js :

```
...
case 'FETCH_DATA':
    let defaultPayload = { propA: 'asdf', propB: new Date() ... etc }

return {
    ...state,
    fetchDataPayload: action.payload || defaultPayload
};
```

Or if you want to have a mix between initialData and your true payload :

```
...
case 'FETCH_DATA':
    let defaultPayload = { propA: 'asdf', propB: new Date() ... etc }

return {
    ...state,
    fetchDataPayload: {...defaultPayload, ...action.payload}
};
```

In that case, if common properties are found in action.payload it will override those defines in defaultPayload.

Hope this helps !